# Do I need ARM or ARM64 Gapps for an asus zenfone 2 laser ZE500KL?

Tags: applications, arm-processors

I was wondering if there is significant difference regarding compatibility and readiness when it comes to ARM or ARM64 Gapps?

According to the qualcomm website, the chipset I have supports both 32 and 64bit. I was wondering which one to choose for more stability.

UPDATE: http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/d8d3356c <----it looks like it is ARM, but on the website of the chipset it say ARM64. Confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than wasting time checking your SoC architecture, why not check your ROM's build architecture instead? The following methods are available for you.

1. The existence of `/system/bin/linker64` indicates that your ROM is built for ARM64 (or more formally, AArch64), as well as these things

   ```
   File: /system/bin/linker64
         /system/bin/app_process64
   Directory: /system/lib64/
              /system/vendor/lib64
   ```

If these things don't exist, it means that you're running a ARM 32-bit ROM.

2. Open `/system/build.prop` in any text editor and look for `ro.product.cpu.abi`. If its value is `arm64-v8a` then your ROM is ARM64. If its value is 'armeabi-v7a' or something else, safely believe it's an ARM ROM.

I suggest checking your ROM architecture instead of CPU architecture, as it sometimes occurs that an ARM ROM is installed on an ARM64 device.

FYI, your SoC, Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 is in fact ARM64 as its core architecture is ARM Cortex-A53, the very first 64-bit core architecture from ARM.

Comment: `...it sometimes occurs that an ARM ROM is installed on an ARM64 device.` - well observed. +1

Answer (score 0):

Qualcomm website says "CPU Bit Architecture: 64-bit" therefore I would flash opengapps arm64, if you get an error during install (it won't affect your system), use the arm version instead.

Answer (score 0):

Checking your phones hardware is easy. 
Open a terminal and 
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo

The os being 32bit or 64bit is a different question. And ibug answers it well. 
Which answers my question. Are arm64 soc's compatible with 32 bit apps. 
That is down to the os being 32bit or 64bit & multi-arch.

Comment: Where do I find terminal on my phone?..

Comment: Download a terminal app in play store.

Answer (score 0):

the trick to check the BUILD.PROP file is pretty neat.

Open /system/build.prop in any text editor and look for ro.product.cpu.abi. If its value is arm64-v8a then your ROM is ARM64. If its value is 'armeabi-v7a' or something else, safely believe it's an ARM ROM.